# Lag in vba vlookup

Tags: vba, excel

I'm running VBA code using vlookup, however, it take a few seconds to complete, despite the sheet that has the rows only has less than 150 rows.

The lag mainly appears during the generation of col 23.

The main sheet that contains this code has about 2300 rows.

Is the lag normal or is my coding inefficiency getting the best of me?

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    thisrow = Target.Row

    If Target.Column = 21 Then
        ' Generate the problem comments
        ' Declare some variables
        Dim CodeString As String
        Dim codeArr() As String
        Dim isPI As Boolean
        isPI = False

        ' Reset the impact, comment and origin cells
        Cells(thisrow, 22).Value = ""
        Cells(thisrow, 23).Value = ""
        Cells(thisrow, 25).Value = ""

        ' For esthetics, remove spaces in the cell
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Cells(thisrow, 21).Value = Replace(Cells(thisrow, 21).Value, " ", "")
        Application.EnableEvents = True

        ' Get the code(s)
        CodeString = Cells(thisrow, 21).Value
        codeArr = Split(CodeString, Chr(59))

        ' Error code rows
        ErrLastRow = Sheets("lookup error codes").Cells(Sheets("lookup error codes").Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

        ' There's more than one code
        If UBound(codeArr) > 0 Then
            For i = 0 To UBound(codeArr)
                If i < UBound(codeArr) Then
                    Cells(thisrow, 23).Value = Cells(thisrow, 23).Value & Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(CInt(codeArr(i)), Sheets("lookup error codes").Range("$A$2:$C$" & ErrLastRow).Value, 2, False) & "; "
                Else
                    Cells(thisrow, 23).Value = Cells(thisrow, 23).Value & Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(CInt(codeArr(i)), Sheets("lookup error codes").Range("$A$2:$C$" & ErrLastRow).Value, 2, False)
                End If
            Next i

            ' Check to see if anything is pay impacting
            For Each code In codeArr
                If Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(CInt(code), Sheets("lookup error codes").Range("$A$2:$C$" & ErrLastRow).Value, 3, False) <> "" Then
                    isPI = True

                    ' We only needed one
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next code
        Else
            ' There's only one code
            Cells(thisrow, 23).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Cells(thisrow, 21).Value, Sheets("lookup error codes").Range("$A$2:$C$" & ErrLastRow).Value, 2, False)

            If Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Cells(thisrow, 21).Value, Sheets("lookup error codes").Range("$A$2:$C$" & ErrLastRow).Value, 3, False) <> "" Then
                isPI = True
            End If
        End If

        ' There is a code that is pay impacting
        If isPI = True Then
            Cells(thisrow, 22).Value = "X"
        End If

        ' Modify the origin of error with common origins
        Dim Comment As Range, OrigErr As Range
        Set Comment = Range(Cells(thisrow, 23).Address)
        Set OrigErr = Range(Cells(thisrow, 25).Address)
        OrigErr.Value = ""
        If InStr(1, Comment.Value, "aaa", vbBinaryCompare) Or _
            InStr(1, Comment.Value, "bbb", vbBinaryCompare) Or _
            InStr(1, Comment.Value, "ccc", vbBinaryCompare) Then
                OrigErr.Value = "ddd"
        ElseIf InStr(1, Comment.Value, "eee", vbBinaryCompare) Then
            OrigErr.Value = "fff"
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Changing a cell's value to `""` is triggering a change event. Disable events before changing anything on the worksheet and disable calculation if the changed cells affect other formulas.

Comment: What's intended to happen if target is more than a single cell?

Comment: @Jeeped's comment is just good practice when doing vba period. There's also disabling screen updating if the code is moving from worksheet to worksheet as well. A few good tricks to boost speed.

Comment: @LuxClaridge even better practice is to write code that's fundamentally more efficient, i.e. working with 2D variant arrays instead of manipulating cells and ranges, and writing to cells in batches that "dump" 2D variant arrays onto a range instead of looping.

Answer (score 2):

Changing a cell's value to "" is triggering a change event. Disable events before changing anything on the worksheet and disable calculation if the changed cells affect other formulas.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Target.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub

    If Target.Column = 21 Then
        ' Generate the problem comments

        ' Declare some variables
        Dim CodeString As String, codeArr As Variant
        Dim isPI As Boolean, thisRow As Long

        On Error GoTo safe_exit
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

        thisRow = Target.Row
        isPI = False

        ' Reset the impact, comment and origin cells
        Cells(thisRow, 22) = vbNullString
        Cells(thisRow, 23).Value = vbNullString
        Cells(thisRow, 25).Value = vbNullString

        ' For esthetics, remove spaces in the cell
        Cells(thisRow, 21) = Replace(Cells(thisRow, 21).Value, " ", vbNullString)

        ' Get the code(s)
        CodeString = Cells(thisRow, 21).Value
        codeArr = Split(CodeString, Chr(59))

        ' Error code rows
        ErrLastRow = Sheets("lookup error codes").Cells(Sheets("lookup error codes").Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

        ' Doesn't matter if there is one code or many
        For i = LBound(codeArr) To UBound(codeArr)
            If i < UBound(codeArr) Then
                Cells(thisRow, 23).Value = Cells(thisRow, 23).Value & Application.VLookup(CLng(codeArr(i)), Sheets("lookup error codes").Range("A:C"), 2, False) & "; "
            Else
                Cells(thisRow, 23).Value = Cells(thisRow, 23).Value & Application.VLookup(CLng(codeArr(i)), Sheets("lookup error codes").Range("A:C"), 2, False)
            End If
        Next i

        ' Check to see if anything is pay impacting
        For Each code In codeArr
            If Application.VLookup(CLng(code), Sheets("lookup error codes").Range("A:C"), 3, False) <> "" Then
                ' There is a code that is pay impacting
                Cells(thisRow, 22).Value = "X"
                ' We only needed one
                Exit For
            End If
        Next code

        If isPI Then
        End If

        ' Modify the origin of error with common origins
        Dim Comment As Range, OrigErr As Range
        Set Comment = Cells(thisRow, 23)
        Set OrigErr = Cells(thisRow, 25)
        OrigErr.Value = vbNullString
        If InStr(1, Comment.Value, "aaa", vbBinaryCompare) Or _
           InStr(1, Comment.Value, "bbb", vbBinaryCompare) Or _
           InStr(1, Comment.Value, "ccc", vbBinaryCompare) Then
                OrigErr.Value = "ddd"
        ElseIf InStr(1, Comment.Value, "eee", vbBinaryCompare) Then
            OrigErr.Value = "fff"
        End If
    End If

safe_exit:
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
```

To the start of your code and

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
```

to the end.

Comment: Generally I see `Application.Calculation` as the property being changed. It appears that `Application.Calculate` is a method but the documentation is kind of unclear. Do they do the same thing?

Comment: `Application.Calculate` should force a calculation cycle; I have no idea what trying to set it to false does. Error control is another option typical within a Worksheet_Change.

Comment: sorry that was my fault.  I was trying to write Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual but I was typing faster than I was thinking